# Finding the number of terms in an arithmetic series

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic, arithmetic-progressions

Consider the arithmetic series $-6,1,8,15....$
Find the least number of terms so that the sum of the series is greater than $1000$.

I don't know how to do it,the only thing I got is this:

$a=-6 \\
d=7$

$n^{\text{th}}$ term is given by $a+(n-1)*d
              =-6+7n-7
              =7n-13$

Please help..

Comment: Going forward I might suggest - [mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: There is a formula to get the sum of terms of AP. [n*(2*a+(n-1)*d)]/2. Basically it means n*(average of first and nth term). Try with this formula

Answer (score 2):

For your $a_k=7k-13$, consider that $\sum_{k=1}^na_k=\frac{1}{2}n(a_1+a_n)$. You want this to be greater than $1000$, hence \begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}n(a_1+a_n)=\frac{1}{2}n(-6+7n-13)>1000
\end{equation}

Can you take it from here?